# What is the grammatical designation of "that" in "...that she may have..."?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, early-modern-english, old-english

The following sentence is the Modern English translation of a line from [the Old English poem *Judith*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judith_(poem)):

> He (God) advanced a gracious favour to her, **that she may have** a steadfast faith.

My question isn’t really about the Old English. The conjunction *that* introduces a sense purpose like *so that*.

My question: what do we call this *that* (without the *so*), which presents a purpose?

Comment: Note that this construction is "early Modern English" - it is archaic in current English.

Comment: This _that_ is a complementizer. It's equivalent to _in order that_, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In older English, the conjunction *that* could be used to mean **so that, in order that**, indicating a purpose. It is still alive in modern English, but it sounds a bit old fashioned outside formal language. It is still a **conjunction**.

Answer (score 0):

*That* in this context is a restriction.  The *gracious favor* was only given to her to provide a *steadfast faith*, and not for any other reason.  Without the *that* clause, the sentence:

> He (God) advanced a gracious favour to her.

allows the reader to infer any ulterior motive.  To prevent any doubt or confusion, the poem presents a restriction via *that*.